# How to change the background color of a selected ComboBox item? uwp

Tags: c#, combobox, uwp

I'm developing an application for a Windows 10 Mobile device and I'm struggling to handle the styling for the ComboBox control, more specifically, the selected item's background color.

> Without editing the Foreground or Background properties of the
>   control;

**How the ComboBox is displayed prior to selecting any items:**

[image: pre-selected ComboBox]

**The expanded ComboBox**

[image: expanded combo box]

**The ComboBox with "2" as the selected item**

[image: expanded combo box after selecting item]

I can't seem to find any properties for the control such as SelectedItemBackgroundColor and changing the Foreground and Background properties doesn't affect the problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you look into the [documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/mt299115.aspx), you can see the default style of `ComboBoxItem` uses the `SystemControlHighlightListAccentLowBrush` brush as the background of `SelectedItem`. You can redefine this resource in your app or you can copy the default `Style` and replace the `Background` brush in `Selected` `VisualState` with a custom brush.